# Change AppBarButton circle and icon and label color windows phone 8.1 Page bottom app bar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, commandbar

I want to customize the circle and icon color of AppBarButton. So I tried following style but it does not work. In XAML, it show circle color green. But when I run the circle color is not changed

```
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle1" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent" Width="100">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,14,0,13" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" Width="40">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="40" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="40"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="OutlineEllipse" Height="40" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="40"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" Width="88"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My BottomAppBar

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
<CommandBar>
     <AppBarButton Name="MenuButton" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" Icon="AllApps" Click="MenuBtn_Click" Label="Menu"/>
</CommandBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Order to change the foreground color of the app bar button you need to set the foreground of the command bar then it will work. The only thing in that is everything in the command bar namely the ellipsis, the buttons and the secondary commands will be of same color.

```
    <CommandBar Foreground=Green>
     <AppBarButton Name="MenuButton" Icon="AllApps" Click="MenuBtn_Click" Label="Menu"/>
    </CommandBar>
```

Hope this helps!